# Why does 2nd block of this code, where it takes input whether to swim or wait for boat, displays none when I run it?

Tags: python

[Image of the program in question which when run displays "none" when 2nd block of code is executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK63F.png)

Comment: Please add your code as text to your question (and pay attention to [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)). There are [many good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), why images of code are not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you used print function inside the [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function. Rearange the code and write the statement inside the print to inside of the input.

correct use:

```
input("foo, boo")
```

incorrect use:

```
input(print("foo, boo"))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using a print function inside your `input()` function. Please read about the use of  `input()` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

Correct use:

```
choice2 = input("You have arrived at a river bank ...")
choice3 = input("You have arrived at an island ...")
```

Incorrect use:

```
choice2 = input(print("You have arrived at a river bank ..."))
choice3 = input(print("You have arrived at an island ..."))
```

Comment: Small correction: In Python 3 `print` is a function. `print` was a statement in the late Python 2.

Comment: Thanks for the correction - I have edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the print() in your second code block:

From:

```
choice2 = input(print("Your questions?\n")).lower()
```

To:

```
choice2 = input("Your questions?\n").lower()
```

When you use print(), your question string is not passed to input(), which outputs a None.